# $\begin{vmatrix}~E\Big[\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n}X_i\Big]~\end{vmatrix} \le \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n}\begin{vmatrix}E[X_i]\end{vmatrix}$

Tags: expected-value

What's the name of this inequality:

$$\begin{vmatrix}\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n}X_i\end{vmatrix} \le \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n}\begin{vmatrix}X_i\end{vmatrix}$$

$$\begin{vmatrix}~E\Big[\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n}X_i\Big]~\end{vmatrix} \le \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n}\begin{vmatrix}E[X_i]\end{vmatrix}$$

Comment: Triangle inequality?

Comment: you even have $$\left|\mathbb E\left[\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\right]\right|\leq \sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb E[|X_i|]$$

Comment: The second inequality also involves the linearity of the esperance.